# Snowpipe fails to read AVRO compressed by DEFLATE exported from BigQuery

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to import data exported from BigQuery as AVRO and compressed as DEFLATE. The only encoding common to both is DEFLATE besides NONE.
I am exporting one of publicly available datasets bigquery-public-data:covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data with 13,343,598 rows. I am using the following command to export:

```
bq extract --destination_format=AVRO --compression=DEFLATE bigquery-public-data:covid19_open_data.covid19_open_data gs://staging/covid19_open_data/avro_deflate/covid19_open_data_2_*.avro
```

The command creates 17 files in GCP. When I query the data in the files with command:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM @shared.data_warehouse_ext_stage/covid19_open_data/avro_deflate;
```

I only get a count of 684,5021 rows. To troubleshoot the error in the pipe I issue the command:

```
SELECT * from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'covid19_open_data', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1, current_timestamp())));
```

The error reported by the pipeline is as follows:

> Invalid data encountered during decompression for file: 'covid19_open_data_3_000000000006.avro',compression type used: 'DEFLATE', cause: 'data error'

The SQL for the File Format command is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT monitoring_blocking.dv_avro_deflate_format TYPE = AVRO COMPRESSION = DEFLATE;
```

I know the problem is only related to the compression being DEFLATE. There are only two compressions for AVRO that are common for both BigQuery and Snowflake NONE and DEFLATE. I also created two pipes one file format AVRO with compression NONE and the second with CSV and GZIP. They both load data into the table. The two AVRO pipelines are a mirror of each other except for the file format. Here is snippet of the SQL for the pipe:

> CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE covid19_open_data_avro
> AUTO_INGEST = TRUE
> INTEGRATION = 'GCS_PUBSUB_DATA_WAREHOUSE_NOTIFICATION_INT' AS
> COPY INTO covid19_open_data(
> location_key
> ,date
> ,place_id
> ,wikidata_id
> ...
> )
> FROM
> (SELECT
> $1:location_key
> ,$1:date AS date
> ,$1:place_id AS place_id
> ,$1:wikidata_id AS wikidata_id
> ...
> FROM @shared.staging/covid19_open_data/avro_deflate)
> FILE_FORMAT = monitoring_blocking.dv_avro_deflate_format;

Comment: If the no compression version works, it sounds like a bug. I would be temped to get the uncompressed AVRO files and compress them locally and then try load those. If that works it implies it's writing layer, and if the locally compress fail to load, it's snowflake handling. This can be double checked by flipping the test, and locally uncompressing the compressed output files, and check snowflake can read those, that eliminated the write stage again. The last point this only works if the compression is done on the file as a whole as compared to in file stream compression.

Comment: And if it's a Snowflake bug, I'd open a support ticket. With your detail reproduction included.

Comment: Btw, is this covid data a sample for the question, or the goal of the export? Snowflake already has an awesome COVID-19 data provider on the Marketplace, if that's what you need: https://www.snowflake.com/datasets/starschema-covid-19-epidemiological-data/  -- In any case, this is a good Avro question to solve on the Snowflake side.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within Snowflake. When we change the compression format in the FILE FORMAT definition to AUTO it worked

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_schema.avro_compressed_format
TYPE = AVRO
COMPRESSION = DEFLATE;
```

to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_schema.avro_compressed_format
TYPE = AVRO
COMPRESSION = AUTO;
```